# Facebook API Error message '(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (adaccounts) on node type (Page)'

Tags: php, facebook

I'm getting the error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message '(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (adaccounts) on node type (Page)'

When trying to use the Facebook Marketing API.

This is my code: (I've got the correct values in where the # is.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang = "en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title> Home </title>

</head>

<body>

    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '#',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.6'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdUser;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;

// Initialize a new Session and instanciate an Api object
Api::init("#", "#", "#");

// The Api object is now available trough singleton
$api = Api::instance();


$me = new AdUser('me');
$my_adaccount = $me->getAdAccounts()->current();

print_r($my_adaccount->getData());


?>






















</body>


</html>
```

Comment: What “me” refers to, depends on the kind of access token used. Looks like you are making this request using a page access token, where it should be a user access token.

Comment: Okay, now I'm getting this error:  You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API